# DisplayMemberPath for ComboBox in WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datatable, datarow

I have `DataTable` containing necessary `DataRows`, which I want to display in `ComboBox`. 
The second `DataColumn` is called *`VALUE`* and I want to make it a `DisplayMember`.

However, all I see in `ComboBox` - *empty* lines according to number of `DataRows`.
What am I doing wrong?

```
DataTable dataTableManufacturers;
dm = new DatabaseManagement.DatabaseManagement(Properties.Settings.Default.DBServer,Properties.Settings.Default.DBName, Properties.Settings.Default.DBUser, Properties.Settings.Default.DBPassword);
dataTableManufacturers = dm.getManufacturers();

combxManufacturer.DisplayMemberPath = "VALUE";

foreach (DataRow row in dataTableManufacturers.Rows)
{
    combxManufacturer.Items.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: try setting `combxManufacturer.ItemsSource =  dataTableManufacturers;` rather than adding the rows individually.

Comment: @paul You are rightm but need to assing to dataTableManufacturers.Rows .Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DisplayMemberPath` should be `"[VALUE]"` because you intend to use [this indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5.aspx) (not a property) to get at the data. See [binding path syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

As an (important!) aside, the "WPF way" is to set up the control's `ItemSource` instead of manually adding to the `Items` collection.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a beginner so found your answer valuable!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `combxManufacturer.ItemsSource =  dataTableManufacturers.Rows;` rather than adding the rows individually.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `combxManufacturer.ItemsSource` property

```
combxManufacturer.ItemsSource = dataTableManufacturers.AsDataView;
```

and no need to add items

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out and I know for a fact it works.

```
private DataTable testTable = new DataTable();
        testTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]
            {
                new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)), 
                new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), 
            });
        var row = testTable.NewRow();
        row[0] = 1;
        row[1] = "My Name";
        testTable.Rows.Add(row);
        myTestCmb.ItemsSource = TestTable.AsDataView();

<ComboBox x:Name ="myTestCmb" DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```